# Characterization of analytic functions by exponential functions

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be an analytic function on domain $D$ such that $f(z) \neq 0, \forall z \in D.$

Could anyone advise me how to prove $f= e^{h},$ for some analytic $h$ on $D \ ?$ Thank you.

Comment: Can't you take the log of $f$ uniquely as it's never zero?

Comment: For instance the function $z$ on the domain consisting of points with norm greater than $1$ and less than $2$ is never zero, and can't be written as $ e^h$ for some analytic function on the domain...

Comment: Thank you. So is the statement true if $f$ is entire instead?

Comment: Could you also elaborate on your counterexample?

Comment: The statement is true if the domain $D$ is simply connected.In particular it is true for $D=\Bbb C$ which is simply connected.

Answer (score 2):

This is more of a comment really. intuitively what we are doing is as follows. Suppose that once could write $f = e^h$ for some $h$ an analytic function. Then $h' = f'/f$. Now we want to show that such an h actually exists. choose any point $z_0 \in \Omega$(any domain). Let $h(z_0) = c$. Now define

$h(z) := \int_{\gamma} h'(w)dw$

where $\gamma$ is any path in the domain connecting $z_0$ to $z$. First we need to check whether this function is well defined. That is $\gamma, \gamma'$ are two such paths then

$\int_{\gamma} h'(w)dw - \int_{\gamma'} h'(w)dw = 0$.

That is for any loop at $z_0$ say $\alpha$, $\int_{\alpha} h'(w)dw = 0$. Now if the domain is simply connected this is true using stokes theorem. Once the function $h$ is well defined on $\Omega$ then it will be analytic by definition(integral of an analytic function). We are done.